# Check_overlap not working in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm new to R and `ggplot2`. I'm working with `ggplot2` and I'm having trouble getting `check_overlap=TRUE` to have any effect on my geom_text. Here is an example of my code:

```
require(ggplot2)
LV_plot = ggplot(plotFrame,aes(x=Age,y=fit))
#... plotting other things
my_text = geom_text(data=myDataFrame,mapping=aes(x=Age,y=myDataFrame$firstVolume, label=paste(myDataFrame$firstVolume)),angle=70,size=6,check_overlap=TRUE)
LV_scatterNorm = geom_point(data=myDataFrame,aes(x=Age,y=firstVolume),size=4.0)
LV_lineNorm = geom_line(data=myDataFrame,aes(x=Age,y=firstVolume),size=1.2)
```

This creates multiple text elements but check_overlap=TRUE has no effect on their overlap - they overlap most of the time.

Here is my data:

myDataFrame:

```
         firstVolume Age
1           26502.54  56
2           28335.54  57
```

plotFrame:

```
    Age      fit       se       sd
 1   43 10481.39 2555.560 16036.31
 2   44 11164.03 2390.339 16036.31
 3   45 11849.98 2225.044 16036.31
 4   46 12537.78 2063.854 16036.31
 5   47 13225.95 1910.410 16036.31
 6   48 13913.05 1767.397 16036.31
 7   49 14597.60 1636.212 16036.31
 8   50 15278.15 1516.911 16036.31
 9   51 15950.26 1408.477 16036.31
 10  52 16612.87 1315.257 16036.31
 ...etc.
```

My result looks like this:

[image]

This is in R 3.1.1. What am I doing wrong?

(I tried to install ggrepel but it seems that ggrepel is not available for this version of R.)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide the example data and a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you sure you are using the most recent version of ggplot2?  Your example works for me, removing one of the labels.

Comment: It might not be the most recent, since I'm not using the most recent version of R. Is check_overlap a relatively new feature?

Comment: Yes, introduced in ggplot2 2.0.0 per [release notes](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/releases/tag/v2.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no example data, I tried this using the example data from the package. As such, `check_overlap` works fine.

You may need to reduce the size of your labels if that's making it impossible to avoid overlaps.

```
require(ggplot2)
data("mtcars")
mtcars
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)))
p

p + geom_text()
# Avoid overlaps
p + geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE)
```

Please provide a reproducible example if this does not solve your problem and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I updated my question to include example code.